# Managing different opt out per Business Unit with the same short code

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, sms, sendsmsactivity, mobilestudio

I will soon be implementing MobileConnect on SFMC. I have several BUs, 1 for each brand, and one short code shared for all brands. Since the STOP keyword is global to the short code, meaning that if a subscriber texts STOP for brand 1 he won't be able to receive any communication from brand2, brand3, brand4, how can i do to manage different opt out by brand ?

Answer (score 0):

In the Administration tab in Mobile Connect, you can edit the Account STOP keyword and personalize it based on your brand.

This way, if any contacts would be opting out, they would be only unsubscribed from the short/long code that belongs to your designated brand and not globally.